# blazor radzen grid using radzen dialog yes/no

Tags: c#, blazor

i am using radzen for blazor, how can i get the TItem="MailTemplate" passed in the yes/no dialog service ?

```
  <RadzenGrid @ref="m_gridTemplates" Data="@m_emailTemplates" TItem="MailTemplate" AllowScrolling="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Single">



<RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Icon="close" Size="ButtonSize.Small" Click=@(args => DialogService.Confirm("Are you sure?", "Delete Template (" +mailTemplate.FileName + ")", new ConfirmOptions() { OkButtonText = "Yes", CancelButtonText = "No" })) MouseEnter="@(args => ShowTooltip(args, new TooltipOptions(){ Position = TooltipPosition.Top ,Text = "Delete Template"}))"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this is a bit late, but I just had the same question, and was helped by this answer in the Radzen forums:
https://forum.radzen.com/t/confirmation-modal-dialog/4069/8

The basic idea is that instead of directly calling the `DialogService.Confirm` method, you call it from your own method which you have passed whatever you need to.

In case of link rot:

```
<RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Icon="delete" Text="Delete" Click="@(args => ConfirmDelete(yourObject.Id))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true"></RadzenButton>
```

```c#
public async Task ConfirmDelete(int id)
{
    var confirmationResult = await this.DialogService.Confirm("Are you sure?", "Dialog Title", new ConfirmOptions { OkButtonText = "Yes", CancelButtonText = "No" });
    if (confirmationResult == true)
    {
        //Delete logic for id
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works well and much clearer answer than on the Radzen forum (https://forum.radzen.com/t/how-to-show-a-message-yes-no-before-delete-record/1700/19).

Answer (score 0):

TItem="MailTemplate" looks like a type, not like a value.
Note, that i am using RadzenDataGrid, not RadzenGrid.
Here is a sample of my code, modifying Type "Order", with value "order", and from a data source "Orders"

```
<RadzenGrid Data="@Orders" TItem="Order" AllowScrolling="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Single">
    <Columns>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Context="ord" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="130px" Title="Remove order reference">
            <Template Context="ord">
                <RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Icon="assignment_turned_in" Size="ButtonSize.Small" Click="@(args => editOrder(ord))"></RadzenButton>
            </Template>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>
    </Columns>
</RadzenGrid>

@Code{
    async Task editOrder(Order order)
    {
       order = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Marko, The problem Lies in the dialog service. I want to call it with yes/no buttons . When yes is clicked, i need to call a delete function,with the current Titem.